# How does assigning methods to each other work? ( " __call__ = __getattr__ " )

Tags: python

I only knew about assigning values to variables etc. But in this case, assigning a method to another method? How does that even work?

What the code lines below do? Is there a name for this kind of usage.

```
__repr__ = __str__
__call__ = __getattr__
```

**Example 1**

```
class Chain(object):
  def __init__(self,path=''):
    print("Constructor.")
    self.__path=path
  def __getattr__(self,path):
    print("getattr method called. path: %s" % path)
    return Chain(self.__path+'/'+path)
  def __str__(self):
    print("String metod called %s" % self.__path)
    return self.__path
  # This part runs before init!
  print("Weird statements.")
  __repr__=__str__
  __call__=__getattr__


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Chain()
    ## Print function calls __call__ and __getattr__ methods, first getattr for 'users' attribute, then 'calls' for 'michael' string argument.
    print(c.users("Michael"))
```

Output:

```
Weird statements.
Constructor.
getattr method called. path: users
Constructor.
getattr method called. path: Michael
Constructor.
String metod called /users/Michael
/users/Michael
```

- c.users # invokes getattr method
- c.users('michael') # invokes call method, but how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What the code lines below do? Is there a name for this kind of usage.

There's no name because there's nothing special to it. It just assigns one variable to an other. `__repr__ = __str__` is the exact same thing as `b = a`, it just creates a second reference (with a different name) to the same object.

The "magic" is that Python's class body basically acts as a function, it's code which is executed sequentially, and at the end all the "local variables" are collected and passed to the class constructor (not to be confused with the class's constructor) to become attributes of the class, which is what methods are in Python. But before that final step, it's just code that gets executed.

TBH this specific assignment is also useless (or more properly the wrong way around) as `__str__` delegates to `__repr__`, so you could just override `__repr__` if you want both to be the same thing.

That aside:

> ```
> self.__path=path
> ```

This is very bad style, you should not use it. Name mangling in Python exists for reasons related to *inheritance*, they've got nothing to do with "information hiding" and they're not a way to create "private members". If you want to specify that a member is "private", the convention is to use a *single* underscore prefix.